# Passing a multi-dimensional array to a function in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

I wrote this function to swap values in a multi-dimensional array with my understanding that arrays are pointers.

```
void
swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

However when I try to use the function

```
swap(board[d-1][d-2]), board[d-1][d-33];
```

I get these errors from the compiler and I don't know why:

```
fifteen.c: in function 'init':
fifteen.c:166:9: error: passing argument 1 of 'swap' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-werror]
fifteen.c:45:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
fifteen.c:166:9: error: passing argument 2 of 'swap' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-werror]
fifteen.c:45:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @chris what are they? mmm IMHO, I thought the where a big chuck of memory that you navigate through according to the data type being handles, ex.: `int64_t num  = 1234;` and `memcpy(buf, &num, sizeof(num))` in this case `num` behaves as an array of 8 bytes. ex.: `char text[] = "...";` then `int32_t *ptr=(int32_t*)&text[0];` and when you `ptr++;` the content of `*ptr` will be the next 4 bytes inside `text`.

Comment: @Kira, Arrays can decay into pointers, but they are not pointers themselves. Try comparing `sizeof`s: http://liveworkspace.org/code/853fc936ff59eee2994ab28ca0c02e92

Comment: @chris, thanks for the example. It worked as you claim, but I won't lie, I'm a little skeptical about this right now. You're making me doubt XD, now I feel like I need to make an open question about this to convince myself. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: @Kira, There are some good array resources on this site and on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`board[d-1][d-2]` and `board[d-1][d-33]` are `int`. To swap the both, you have to pass their addresses:

```
swap (&board[d - 1][d - 2]), &board[d - 1][d - 33];
```

If you are using `swap (board[d - 1][d - 2]), &board[d - 1][d - 33])`, the instruction `int tmp = *a;` will try to access to the value on the address `board[d - 1][d - 2]`: this make no sense! Because you are using pointers, you have to pass the address of your variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the addresses (`swap()` expects two `int *`):

```
swap (&board[d-1][d-2], &board[d-1][d-33]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing wrong argument

> swap (board[d-1][d-2]), board[d-1][d-33]);

you have to pass the address of the variable actually.So the correct way of calling this function is below.

> swap (&board[d-1][d-2]), &board[d-1][d-33]);

I think this will help you.